# Keycloack login Integration in android using web view

Tags: android, retrofit2, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to integrate keycloack login and register functionality in android app using a webview loading its url as that is wanted from the client.But i am struggling to retireve username and email the user used to login which is entered in the web view.Upon alot of research i found it can be decoded from accesstoken using JWT in jwt.io website.But when i decode the accesstoken got from api its not having any claims like email or username.
I am loading the below url in webview

```
https://mydoamin.in/auth/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=Android
```

after login,i am getting a code in redirect url and using that code to login using this api
Endopoint myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
Fields

```
client_id-myclientid
grant_type=client_credentials
client_secret=xxx-xxx-xx---
code=(code got from redirect url)
```

I am getting succes response with access token , but have no claims for  username or email.

But when i change grant_type to password and pass a test username and password , in that access token the email and username claims are present.

Basically i want to use web view itself and retireve the user info from the accesstoken.I think the issue is with mappers.But how to configure it?

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapper for your clients to map needed attributes from your user to an access token

Step to create a mapper:

1.Go to your clients detail page

2.Open tab client scopes

3.Open the default scope of your clients (it should be highlighted) [image]

4.1 If you just want to add email you can go for a predefined mapper for email

4.2 If you want to add a specific user attribute, choose configure new mapper -> User attribute -> Filled needed information

5.After adding a new mapper, try to login again to have a new access token, it should work now

Hope this help

Comment: it didnt work and the default scope .i couldnt find a place like the image you sent for scope

Comment: Can you give me the version of your Keycloak, I am using the latest so maybe it have some differences

Comment: 21.1.1 i think.

Comment: To check the Keycloak version you can go to master realm -> Server info, the version will be noted in the server info

Comment: Weird, if the version is > 18 you should see the client scopes tab in the client detail page. It should be there

Comment: Even after i add mappers , its not coming with token

Comment: You nearly reach it, now you go to the scope tab, next to the mapper tab and enable the fulle scope